# How to insert a dynamically generated value into a tracking script with javascript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, event-tracking

I'm currently trying to set up accurate revenue tracking between improvely and clickfunnels, and having problems getting a conversion code to work. Basically, the final order  price is generated in the CF confirmation page like so:

```
<div class="totalprice">$67.99</div>
```

And I need to insert that value into the improvely tracking script. This is currently in the header, but I'm thinking placing it in the footer may better insure the dynamic price has already loaded, but I'm not sure. I'm trying to grab the price as avariable, without the $ currency sign, just before the standard improvely script starts.  but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alsearsmd.iljmp.com/improvely.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('.totalprice').innerHTML.replace('$', '');  

improvely.init('alsearsmd', 1);
improvely.conversion({
    goal: 'sale',
    revenue: price,
    reference: '123'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your price assignment doesn't work.

Use this:

```
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('totalprice')[0].innerHTML.replace('$', '');
```

(The classname doesn't need a dot, and we need the first element of the returned array, [0])

Edit:
For multiple divs, here's one way:

```
var price = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('totalprice')).map((div) => {
  return parseFloat(div.innerHTML.replace("$", ""));
}).reduce((a, b) => {
  return a + b;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that when there are multiple items, it actually uses the same class, how could I go about adding up the values of that class? Should I still use the array or something like:

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that when there are multiple items, it actually uses the same class, how could I go about adding up the values of that class? Should I still use the array or something like:        'var total = 0;
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('totalprice')[0].innerHTML.replace('$', '');
for (var i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(price[i].value, 10);
}'

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, at least no in the same <script> tag as the improvely code. Should it be separare? Should any of this go in the footer?

Comment: The code I posted is supposed to replace your `var price = ...` line.

Comment: Yes i Understand that, I did replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('totalprice');
    var price= 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
      price += parseFloat(prices[i].innerHTML.replace('$', ''));
    }

    improvely.init('alsearsmd', 1);
    improvely.conversion({
        goal: 'sale',
        revenue: price,
        reference: ''
    });

}
```

Comment: The $(document).ready(function() {
 was throwing off undefined function errors, but its not working with it or without it.

Comment: It's jQuery and will only work if you also add a jQuery <script> to your HTML.

Comment: It's working fine on the clickfunnels URL you told me it was for

Comment: hmm, you could see it replacing the value? I saw no prices registering in improvely, despite there being sales - so I assume something there was not working.